# How to run Tasks such that the last one started (not completed) wins?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await, task

I'm trying to implement a responsive search text box, where the search results are updated as the user types in the search text. I'm trying to do this using Tasks, but I'm finding that sometimes a previous search finishes after a later search, thereby replacing the new results with old results.

One quick fix is to delay starting the search after the user has stopped typing for half a second or so. However, I think this only hides the problem. I'd like to find a general solution.

So far, I've come up with the following class:

```
public class LastAddedTaskStrategy<T>
{
    private DateTime latest;

    public T Result { get; private set; }

    public async Task Add(Task<T> t)
    {
        var timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        latest = timestamp;

        var currentResult = await t;

        if (timestamp >= latest)
            Result = currentResult;
    }
}
```

The idea is that you can add (and await) as many Tasks as you want (e.g., searches), but only the results of the last added (not last completed) Task wins. So if a previous search finishes after a later search, the `Results` property won't be updated because it's an old result.

Is this a good solution or is there something better?

Comment: So could you cancel any running tasks when a new one is added, since you're just going to throw away their results?

Comment: You should just cancel old tasks, i think.

Comment: Rather than `DateTime.Now` you can do much the same with an `Interlocked.Increment`ed `int` / `long` - to avoid the problem where `DateTime.Now` may have the same value for multiple `Task`s.

Comment: @RufusL I thought about that, but I wasn't exactly sure how to do it. According to Concurrency in C# Cookbook, it's actually possible for a Task to complete successfully even if it's been cancelled (for example, it may be almost finished when cancellation is requested).

Comment: @redcurry When u cancel the task, u can check for Task.Status for Canceled. Cancelled task can be ignored in this way. check out the [system.threading.tasks.taskstatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method for `System.Windows.Forms` controls, that subscribes to their [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged) event. Every time the event is fired an asynchronous method is invoked, and the result of this method is propagated to a handler. The result is propagated only under the condition that the asynchronous method will not be preempted before its completion.

```
public static void OnTextChangedExecute<TResult>(this Control control,
    Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> function,
    Action<TResult> handler)
{
    CancellationTokenSource activeCTS = null;
    control.TextChanged += Event_Handler;

    async void Event_Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        activeCTS?.Cancel();
        TResult result;
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            activeCTS = cts;
            try
            {
                result = await function(cts.Token);
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
                when (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return; // Preempted, don't invoke the handler.
            }
            finally
            {
                if (activeCTS == cts) activeCTS = null;
            }
        }
        handler(result);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextBox1.OnTextChangedExecute(
        ct => SearchAsync(TextBox1.Text, ct), TextBox1_SearchCompleted);
}

async Task<int> SearchAsync(string text, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000, token); // Simulate some cancelable I/O operation
    return Int32.Parse(text);
}

void TextBox1_SearchCompleted(int result)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Result: {result}");
}
```

The `OnTextChangedExecute` method is not thread-safe. It is intended to be called from the UI thread only. It depends on the existence
of a [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext) to work properly.